# MySQL - Get the column value where two values of next column are matched with condition

Tags: php, mysql

**MYSQL** I have a table which has dynamic data, so i handle the dynamic data row wise. I want a column value where two values are matched of same column on one entry such as the below:

| id | rack_id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Red |
| 2 | 101 | 14CM |
| 3 | 101 | Open |
| 4 | 102 | Green |
| 5 | 102 | 14CM |
| 6 | 102 | Open |
| 7 | 103 | Red |
| 8 | 103 | 20CM |
| 9 | 103 | Open |
| 10 | 104 | Red |
| 11 | 104 | 14CM |
| 12 | 104 | Close |

I want `rack_id` Where data is `Red` AND `14CM`. Expected result would be (101,104)

Comment: Have you even tried this? This looks like a pretty simple thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many approaches for your problem. But you can start with a basic approach of joining the data together. With the "INNER JOIN" Keyword you can not only join two different tables, but also the same tables.

The following statement joins example_table into itsself based on the rack_id. That gives you the two data fields you need in one row.

```
SELECT e.rack_id FROM example_table as e INNER JOIN example_table as e2 ON e2.rack_id = e.rack_id AND e.data = "Red" AND e2.data = "14CM"
```

Just have a look into the possible keywords you can use, and how they can help you. If you want to dive a little deeper: have a look at subqueries which would be also a good solution for your problem.

Comment: thanks but i thought following query is better and short      ==>        SELECT e.rack_id FROM example_table as e WHERE data IN ('Red', '14CM') GROUP BY rack_id  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: Hi jawad, yes this also works - you don't even need the alias "as e" since there is only one table in this statement. Please feel free to post this also as an answer to your question, and mark it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do as many conditions as you need for your case you can use `Where` clause like that

> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE data = 'Red' AND data = '14CM';

you can use logic operators `AND` `OR` and `LIKE`

for more information in details
[documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Comment: But this return me 101,102,103,104 also, because 102 contain 14cm and 103 containes red